# Regular Expression for if condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I accept an if condition like the excel expression;

`IF( condition1, value_if_true1, IF( condition2, value_if_true2, value_if_false2 ))`

I want the regular expression to extract each condition for example, when I run the following:
`var matchInfo = REGEXP.exec(fieldExpression);`

I should get something like this as a result: 
`matchInfo[0]=condition1, matchInfo[2]=condition2`

how do I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's *very* hard to make out what you're asking right now. Perhaps a working example of the `if` code, and then a clear statement of what you want to do instead (and why, since `if` is perfectly reasonable most of the time).

Answer (score 0):

Here. It will give you condition1 and condition 2, based on the pattern you gave. Since you are looking for multiple matches, I'm using a while loop to traverse until there are no more matches.

```
var pattern = /IF\(\s(\w+)/g;
var str = 'IF( condition1, value_if_true1, IF( condition2, value_if_true2, value_if_false2 ))';
var myMatches = [];
while ((newMatch = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {
  myMatches.push(newMatch[1]);
}
```

Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: its not working on live sceneario  if(English==40,50,if(Percentage=40,60,70))

Comment: Just mind this is not the same as your sample. In your sample, you had capitalized IF, a space before the condition, and condition was a variable, not an expression. In this new sample you gave, you will need to alter the regex to account for the changed conditions. Change this line: `var pattern = /if\(([\w=]*)/g;`